# Spring +Mongodb Query for adding and removing inner array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, criteria

I want to query, add and remove of an object which is a property in my document. This object is an array and consist of an inner array which I want to query. Below is the mongo response format
 I want to  add or remove array or value from a section class
 I want to add or remove inner array or single value from subcategory class by using Query in Repository...

```
  {  
   "id":"Test",
   "name":"Test",
    "sections":[  
   {  
      "sectionname":"Example1",
      "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],
      "subcategory":[  
         {  
            "Value":"demo",
            "ValueId":"123333333333",
           "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],
         },
         {  
            "Value":"sometest",
            "Value":"6577544333333",
            "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],

         }
      ]
       },
        {  
      "sectionname":"Example2",
      "sectionroles":[""test1", "test2", "test3"],
      "ssubcategory":[  
         {  
             "Value":"demo1",
            "ValueId":"123333333333",
           "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],
           }
          ]
       }
     ]
     }
```

I have a document class

```
 @Document(collection="flowTable")
  public class Test {


    @Id
    private String id;

    private String testName;
    private List<Sections> sections;
   }

  public class Sections{

    private String sectionname;
   private List<String> sectionroles;
   private List<subcategory> subcategory;
    }

     public class subcategory {
     private String Value;
     private String ValueId;
     private List<String> sectionroles;

     }
```

Repository class

```
  @Repository
   public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository< Test, Integer> 
   {

 List<Test> deleteBySections(String name);//Trying this but is not correct
  ????????????????????????????????

 }
```

1) How do I add or remove from on section from a sections property?
2) How do i add or remove inner array or single value from subcategory by using Query in Repository?